# FTPClient (commons net) download and logout don't work

Tags: java, android, apache-commons-net

I'm apologise for my english.

1. I use the following piece of code to download a file from ftp host to Tablet. When I use Wi-Fi everything works well. But when I try to download a file using the mobile Internet, the download stops, but not always, sometimes finishes normally. I've found that stop is always going on "retrieveFile" or "logout", the program comes to these commands and no going further, and simply stands, the icon of data transfer does not blink, stops occur randomly. I tried to use different mobile operators, but there is no difference. What could be the reason?
2. And another question, but It is not so important, I've not found how to get the file size, and used my decision, maybe there is another way to get the file size ?

   private void downloadFile(final String url, final String Message, final String Message2, final Uri uri) {
       final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
       new AsyncTask() {
              private Exception m_error = null;

   ```
          @Override
          protected void onPreExecute() {
           progressDialog.setMessage(Message);
           progressDialog.setCancelable(true);             
           progressDialog.setMax(100);
           progressDialog
             .setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);             
           progressDialog.show();
          }

          @Override
          protected File doInBackground(String... params) {         
                    FileOutputStream fos = null;                        
                    File file = null;
                    FTPClient client = null;                       
                         try{  
                          client = new FTPClient();
                          client.connect(ftp_host,Integer.parseInt(ftp_port));
                          client.login(ftp_user, ftp_password);
                          client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                          client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                          String stat = "";
                          if (url.equals("MobiTrade.apk")){
                              client.changeWorkingDirectory("/var/srv/home/user/mobitrade/update/");}
                       file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),                     
                                  "/MobiTrade/update/MobiTrade.apk");}
                              stat = client.getStatus("/var/srv/home/user/mobitrade/update/MobiTrade.apk");                                                                   
                          else {   
                              client.changeWorkingDirectory("/var/srv/home/user/mobitrade/"+number+"/out/");
                              file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                                  "/MobiTrade/in/"+url);
                       if (url.equals("message.csv")) file.delete();                               
                              stat = client.getStatus("/var/srv/home/user/mobitrade/"+number+"/out/"+url);                                                                
                        } 

                          final Integer FileSize;
                          if (stat.length() >= 64) {
                   stat = stat.substring(49,64);
                   stat = stat.trim();
                   FileSize = Integer.parseInt(stat);
                   }                                                   
                         else {
                   FileSize = 0;
                   }

                          fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

                          CountingOutputStream cos = new CountingOutputStream(fos){                                   
                              protected void beforeWrite(int n){
                                       super.beforeWrite(n);
                                       publishProgress(getCount(), FileSize);
                              }
                          };                              

                          if (url.equals("MobiTrade.apk")){
                              client.retrieveFile("/var/srv/home/user/mobitrade/update/MobiTrade.apk", cos);
                               }   
                          else {       
                              client.retrieveFile("/var/srv/home/user/mobitrade/"+number+"/out/"+url, cos);
                               }           
                      if (url.equals("message.csv")){
                          client.deleteFile("/var/srv/home/user/mobitrade/"+number+"/out/"+url);                                  
                      }            

                          client.logout();                             

                   }
                         catch (Exception e){
                          e.printStackTrace();
                         }
                            finally{
                                 try{
                                  if (fos != null) fos.close();
                                  if (client.isConnected()) {
                                       client.disconnect();
                                   }
                                 }
                                 catch (IOException e){
                                  e.printStackTrace();
                                 }
                            }
                         return file;
                   }

          protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
           progressDialog
             .setProgress((int) ((values[0] / (float) values[1]) * 100));
          };

          @Override
          protected void onPostExecute(File result) {
           if (m_error != null) {
            m_error.printStackTrace();
            return;
           }
           progressDialog.hide();
           if (url.equals("settings.csv"))
               ProcessSettings(url);
           else if (url.equals("MobiTrade.apk"))
               ProcessUpdate();
           else
               ProcessData(url, Message2, uri);
          }
         }.execute(url);
        }
   ```

Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: If it is dependent of connection, it is a configuration issue. Bad connection, firewalls, proxies, intrusion alerts... The random pattern (sometimes it works, sometimes it does not) suggest the first one, but there may be other things.

Comment: at first I also thought that it's a bad connection, but tried a few other mobile operators, and there is the same. I also saw that if the download stops at retrieving the file, it is always at the end, progressbar comes to the end. Thank you for answer

Comment: I can't say anything on why you're having more or less random issues, but the file size question can be easily answered. Use the various list and mlist methods of FTPClient to get references to FTPFile objects which in turn have a getSize method.